# Catch mysql *warning* (not exception) while using Laravel DB Builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a BIGINT field, and for testing I maxxed out the field and then tried to add even more. The following code returns successful without throwing an \Exception, but it is throwing a warning in an sql query and, obviously, not updating the field. How can I catch a warning and return the warning message that the field is at its maximum? *(As you can see I have tried both a DB::transaction and a try/catch without success).*

```
        try {
            DB::transaction(function () use ($data, $quantity) {
                $query = 'INSERT INTO item_user (user_id, item_id, quantity) VALUES '.substr($data,0,-2).' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = GREATEST(`quantity` + '.$quantity.',0)';
                DB::statement($query);

                // subquery to delete any rows left with zero
                DB::table('item_user')->where('quantity',0)->delete();
            });

            return redirect()->route('index')
                ->with( ['flash' => ['message' =>"<i class='fa fa-check-square-o fa-1x'></i> Success! Item totals updated.", 'level' =>  "success"] ] );

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors( $e->getMessage() )->withInput();
        }
```

This returns successful on the page but capturing and running the query directly on SQL gets me the warning and number :

```
Warning Code : 1264
Out of range value for column 'quantity' at row 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about checking `$quantity`before the insert query?

Comment: @Daenu I guess I could do that...but that is an extra query when mysql is already generating the warning. I suppose I was hoping just to catch the warning instead. But it all else fails I suppose I can try that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Edited my answer to fit laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do another statement without catching an Exception (A warning is not an Exception). The syntax:

> SHOW WARNINGS [LIMIT [offset,] row_count]
>
> SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS

After your insert query you may do the following:

---

**Count warnings**

```
DB::statement('SHOW WARNINGS');
$warning = DB::select('SELECT @@warning_count');
```

If a warning occurs it returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#412 (1) {
    ["@@warning_count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
```

or

```
["@@warning_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
```

if no warning occurs.

---

**Warning messages & codes**

To get the warning messages:

```
$warning_messages = DB::select('SHOW WARNINGS');
```

Returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#412 (3) {
    ["Level"]=>
    string(7) "Warning"
    ["Code"]=>
    string(4) "1264"
    ["Message"]=>
    string(79) "Out of range value for column 'quantity' at row 1"
  }
}
```

See the docs about [mySQL Warnings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html)

Comment: Thanks. I had just gotten there using @Gouda Elalfy's info and the mySQL warnings link you provided earlier. It still involved another db hit, but I don't see any other way to get it. In the end I used the following (for anyone looking for the same thing) : 

`if ($warning = DB::select("SHOW WARNINGS") ) {

     $msg = ($warning[0]->Code == 1264) ? "That value exceeds the maximum for the 'quantity' field for one or more users." : 'Mysql Warning #'.$warning[0]->Code.' "'.$warning[0]->Message.'"';

     return redirect()->back()->withErrors( $msg )->withInput();

    } else {
   ...do stuff...`

Comment: FYI - you don't need the DB::raw(), just the `$warning = DB::select("SHOW WARNINGS")` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query after your insert query `SELECT @@warning_count` it will return the warning count so you can check it.